# Do RCDs have a limited life in terms of number of trips?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

In New Zealand, the regulation is to have an RCD (Residual Current Detector) for every three MCBs (Miniature Circuit Breakers).

We have a situation where one of them flips, seemingly randomly, from a few times a week to several times a day.  The frequency is increasing.  Annoyingly one of the circuits is the power to the water pump which, Murphys Law, trips when someone is in the shower.

**Do RCDs have a limited life, in terms of how many times they trip?  Maybe it's tripping more often because it is now damaged.**

I am also wondering, how they work.  I know they compare the current between neutral and phase.  But how do they detect this?  The other two circuits are the Septic Tank and Tesla Solar Gateway.  Because it is intermittent, it is hard to track down the culprit.  I don't think it is the water pump, and neither does my electrician.  He thinks it's probably the Septic Tank.  I think it's the wiring and I intend to trace it later this week.

As a side note, I think this violates the current regulation anyway as I think it says that you should have two lighting circuits and one power circuit for each RCD.

Comment: Seems they are tripping to a problem in the circuit.  They work by comparing current in neutral and/or ground.  Ground safety wire is to protect you if there is current in/on metal housing of a device that you might touch and knock you into a six foot deep hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two very separate issues in my mind with regard to the number of trips:

- Electronics that detect the residual current: These should be able to handle thousands of problem detections without an issue at all.
- The "relay" which does the actual disconnect of the current. This is the part that is likely to fail after too many trips. It isn't actually a traditional relay - but whatever it is, it has to break contact with the current flowing at the time, which could easily be 10A or more, possibly as much as 32A (based on a quick search). And when it fails, it *should* fail open for safety, but of course that means the other two circuits (besides the one causing the fault) will be off until the RCD is replaced. Alternatively, it *could* fail closed, which would be bad because you would have a dangerous situation but think you are protected.

What I would do, if there is panel space to do so, is to separate the three circuits and put an RCD on each one. That will:

- Tell you which circuit is the actual problem, so you will be checking for issues with the septic tank circuit **or** the water pump circuit, and not looking at both of them. (Both have water, so both are potential sources of the problem. Solar? Could be, but my bet is on something involving water.)
- Prevent a problem with one circuit from killing the other circuit.
- If (very big if) you actually have a cumulative problem - e.g., a varying 10ma-20ma problem on one circuit combined with a varying 10ma-20ma problem on another circuit with a 30ma RCD - then this could actually cut down dramatically on the number of trips without having to fix anything at all. Small chance, but possible.

If you have not already done so, first step is to try replacing that RCD, or swapping it with another in the panel if there is an identical one protecting another group of circuits, to eliminate the RCD itself as the source of the problem. More likely it is actually a circuit problem, but a failing RCD is certainly a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

How to measure earth leakage of your appliances that will trip your RCDs...

Get a clamp ammeter.

Manufacture an extension cord with wires instead of cables. You'll need male and female socket, and 3 wires of appropriate color (live, neutral, earth).

Use this cord with your appliance and slip both live and neutral through the clamp meter in the same direction. Do not put the earth wire in the clamp:

[image]

This will measure common mode current flowing into the device and leaking to Earth. So you can get an idea of which device trips the RCD.

If the devices do not have plugs, you can still use the clamp meter on the wires, again only live and neutral in the clamp, not Earth.

It will be more accurate if you twist live and neutral together.

If the clamp meter isn't sensitive enough, you can just make more turns:

[image]

The clamp will measure current going through its opening: if the wires go through it 10 times, it'll measure 10 times the current, making it much more sensitive. For this leakage measurement, both live and neutral must make the same number of turns and in the same turning direction.

All these will only measure AC leakage, unless the clamp also does DC, which is rare.

Another way is to plug your device in a female socket with wires attached, and measure resistance between live/neutral tied together and ground, with an ohmmeter:

[image]

If the ohmmeter shows a value of resistance lower than a few hundred kOhms, there's a problem. However, multimeters use a very low voltage for this, so this will not tell you if the device has an insulation problem that shows up only when high enough voltage is applied, or only when the device is powered up.

So if you measure a low resistance, the device is unsafe. But if you measure a very high resistance, it doesn't mean it is safe. However it is an useful test that will quickly find common faults like water ingress inside connectors, etc.

Do not use the ohmmeter on a powered device, of course.

Comment: Good idea, as I do have such a beast already.  While I can do this easily for the water pump, I am not sure about the septic tank, until I remove the cover.  And I definitely can not do anything about the Tesla Gateway - it's way too complicated to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a 300mA or 30mA?

Usually appliances using inverters needs class A (or, best, class F). If your is AC, replace it with type A.

Also if it's 30mA, replace it with a 300mA (but all appliances must be hard-wired) because leakage occurs in solar inverters.

As for how those works:
they have a "transformer" with 3 coils, one is neutral, second is phase, the third, placed halfway, is the detector. If there's an imbalance a current is induced and the third coil trigger the breaker.

Answer (score 1):

> We have a situation where one of them flips, seemingly randomly

Exactly. We had the same problem with radon detectors, we tried five different ones and none would shut up. Our tenant is fighting lung cancer and the last thing they need is annoying beeping.  Though... I had a dream where our tenant is at the Pearly Gates and God says "What do you mean 'did not help'? I sent you five radon detectors!"

Seriously though. RCDs are safety devices. They are there to keep you safe from stuff.  **They aren't going to do this in a way you find convenient**.

A piece of your equipment has a dangerous ground fault, which is leaking 230V electricity somewhere it should not be.  Given that you connect the problem with water, *it is super important that it be hunted down and corrected*.  Kill it before it kills you.

If you prefer, you can listen to advice to reduce the sensitivity of the RCDs, but I see that as the same as simply removing the annoying device altogether. But then, so is resetting it over and over and never fixing the problem it is detecting.

100mA can kill.  10mA can stun, and if someone is in water, that's the same as a kill because you can't keep your head above water when you're stunned. By American standards, we use 5mA RCD (GFCI) on a per-circuit basis, but only on circuits that get anywhere near water. Euro-style RCDs are a compromise to allow several circuits to be protected by one RCD to save money, at the cost of degraded human safety.

I do not accept that >30mA leakage is a normal condition. If that were true, Americans would never be able to keep our 5mA breakers reset.

Comment: I am not trying to make it unsafe.  I just could not find the right failure data for the RCDs to know if they may have been compromised by now.  Incidentally, at the previous house,  where I had specified non-Chinese fittings, 2 Siemen MCBs failed  3 months after installation.  On investigation, we found that these were the only two that were not  made in Europe.   For now, I have run a lead to the water pump, and neither RCD fails now.  But I still can't rule out mis-wiring as I have found previous errors, I suspect because we have 3 phases.

Answer (score 1):

I used a long extension cord to the water pump. The RCD still tripped.

I had No hope of getting an electrician to come in this busy time, but ours was visiting next door, so asked him to pop in.

I got the Electrician to  replace the MCB with an RCBO (Residual Current Circuit Breaker) for the Tesla Gateway. The RCD still tripped.

The electrician said that the submersible pumps in the septic tank always leak. And constant tripping shortens pump life, so they no longer put an RCD on it. And it's not dangerous as no one's going to climb in without turning the power off.

I got him to megger the bits anyway. The insulation resistance of the blower was 5000M, but the pump was 200M, which is respectable. It means that the RCD is a tad sensitive.

We ended up removing the septic from the RCD.

All working now.

Comment: The only time my septic tank RCD has tripped is when the aerator fan was on the way out and it got wet- I landed up replacing the aerator.  I'm pretty nervous around 240v electricity - especially outdoors, and I personally would not take the risk of not having it on an RCD.  (What if someone digs through the cable with a metal spade?)   [ Meanwhile I have a problem with my new outdoor AP tripping my RCD :( ]